# How to disable the 'Create Bills' button in Yii2

Tags: button, yii2

Please have a look at the screenshot attached

My code in -`form.php` is-

```
<div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary' ]) ?>
    </div>
```

I want to disable this button
[image]

Comment: You want to remove it or disable it? If you want to disable then use `'disabled' => $model->isNewRecord`

Comment: Hi Insane Skull, I'm new to Yii2. Kindly give me the whole code of this line. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `'disabled' => disabled or true`:

```
<?= Html::a('Create Bills', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success',
            'disabled' => true]) 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Insane Skull. Can you check if the create button be disabled on the top page? The page I gave screenshot? I appreciate your help and those who are trying to help me.

Comment: @TanmayMukherjee. Make sure you were applying this on correct button, it was working on my side.

Comment: I'm very very sorry. I gave you a whole wrong code. The code for the button I gave in the screenshot is - "<?= Html::a('Create Bills', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>"
Please let me know how to disable it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Insane Skull and scaisEdge - Thanks for helping. It disables the button but when I'm clicking on it it's still moving to the next page. So I've removed this whole piece of code from the page which removed the button in turn. Both of your answer is correct. I appreciate your help. Thanks once again.

Comment: This is not fair @InsaneSkull     stolen my answer ....  is evident by your first comment  in Question

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding 'disabled' => true in button options this way

```
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', 
  ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary', 
      'disabled' => true, ]) ?>
```

Comment: This serves the purpose. but not exactly the solution I want. This code disables the save button of the next page. I want to disable it beforehand. I'm attaching screenshot what this code does. It disables the update button as well. So this is not the solution I want.

Comment: Dear scaisEdge, check my first comment on question, probably you copied my answer, just tempering `disabled => true`.